# Retrieving the value of a specific attribute via javascript for the onChange attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, onchange

Good morning/afternoon,

Not so much a problem but more of a query. If I have the following code to grab hold of the users selection on a drop-down box (see figure 1), how do I also add the ability to also grab the value of a specific attribute? (see figure 2)

Figure 1:

```
<select onChange="productString(this.value)">
    <option selected>Please Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="Foo"></option>
</select>
```

Figure 2:

```
<select onChange="productString(this)">
    <option selected>Please Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="Foo" id="Bar"></option>
</select>
```

If anyone would be so kind as too show me where I am going wrong in figure 2 it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Dan.

EDIT:::::

Would the following work it collecting the information?

```
function productString(element) {
    var id = element.value;
    var name = element.id;
    var box = element.class;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass though `this`:

```
<select onChange="productString(this)">
```

and then you can get whatever you want:

```
function productString(element) {
  var value = element.value, id = element.id;
  // ...
}
```

[Here is a sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/VZmhL/).

*edit* — oops sorry - the element that's being passed through is, <strike>in IE</strike> everywhere (gee I must be blind), the "select" element, not the "option".  Thus:

```
function productString(element) {
    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select')
        element = element.options[element.selectedIndex];

    var id = element.id;
    var value = element.value;
    // ...
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/VZmhL/1/).

Comment: Ahhh so strictly passing 'this' grabs the whole element instead of a specific attribute?

Comment: Yes, it'll be a reference to the DOM node for the element.

Comment: Would this work if iwrote it like this?  function productString(element) {
 var id = element.value;
 var name = element.id;
 var box = element.class;

Comment: Sure, whatever you need from the element.  You can find good references for the properties of DOM elements at the MDN site (or MSDN for IE).

Comment: Sadly I must be doing something wrong, writing the code that way will not pull back the element.id or element.class

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do the jsfiddle example, when I run that example in jsfiddle it will not callback the element.id in both runs, it calls back the element.value no problems.

Comment: Well it certainly works for me, in Firefox.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Am using FF 7.0.1 I also tried IE 9. same result in both, it wont pick up any value for the element.id. Very strange.